# Подключение класса при отработке условия

Tags: vue.js

При вводе нечётных чисел фон должен становиться красным.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   number: 0,
      isActive: false
  },
  computed: {
   calc(){
     return this.number;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
}

.bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr :class="{ bg: isActive }">
      <td>
      <input type="number" v-model.number="number">
      </td>
      <td> total: {{ calc = calc % 2 === 0 ? calc : { bg: !isActive } }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С использованием официальных руководств - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html.

Как вариант

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    number: 0,
    isActive: false
  },
  computed: {
 calc(){
  return (this.number % 2 != 0 && this.number != 0) ? true : false;
 }
}
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
}

.bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr :class="[{ 'bg': calc }]">
      <td>
      <input type="number" v-model.number="number">
      </td>
      <td> red: {{ calc }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```